# Spring register beans using custom annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, annotations

I need to register some configuration beans from another module. Here is what I have:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public FirstConfig(CustomManager manager, CustomContext context) {
        return manager.get(FirstConfig.class, context);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecondConfig(CustomManager manager, CustomContext context) {
        return manager.get(SecondConfig.class, context);
    }

    @Bean
    public ThirdConfig(CustomManager manager, CustomContext context) {
        return manager.get(ThirdConfig.class, context);
    }
    // some other beans
}
```

The above code works just fine, but as you can see, there are a lot of boilerplate code. So I'm thinking about creating a custom annotation to simplify this. Something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigBeans({FirstConfig.class, SecondConfig.class, ThirdConfig.class})
public class MyConfiguration {
    // some other beans
}
```

The approach I took was to use `@Import` and implement interface `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`

```
public class CustomBeanDefinitionRegistrar implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar
```

and define my annotation like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import({CustomBeanDefinitionRegistrar.class})
public @interface EnableConfigBeans {
    Class<?>[] value();
}
```

However, I'm not able to autowire `CustomManager` or `CustomContext` in `CustomBeanDefinitionRegistrar` since those beans are not ready to use at that phase.

Can someone please give me some suggestions on how to implement this feature? Thanks

Comment: Is there any common interface between FirstConfig, SecondConfig, etc... CustomBeanDefinitionRegistrar is working at bean definition before any beans are created

Comment: @CyrilG. FirstConfig, SecondConfig, etc they don't share any common interface. Since ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar happens in the bean definition registering phase and no bean is available at that time, this approach might be a dead end. Any other thoughts?